# Publishing Azure Function with python packages

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I need help in publishing Azure Function from local system. The function uses App Service Plan and has python code.

I have worked with azure functions in python which used consumption plan. I was able to publish the code from my local machine using

> func azure functionapp publish app_name --build remote

But when I created a new function app with App Service Plan this command does not publish the app.

This is the output I get after running publish command

```
Getting site publishing info...
Updating Application Settings for Remote build...
Creating archive for current directory...
Perform remote build for functions project (--build remote).
Deleting the old .python_packages directory
Uploading 288.84 KB [#############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait........done
Remote build succeeded!
```

This gets build but not published.

Thanks

Comment: I published local data to a function app with App Service Plan. seems nothing unnormal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things works on my side,

1.Create a Function App With App Service Plan.

[image]

2.Create a local Function Project.

[image]
[image]

3.Create a new function.

[image]

[image]
[image]

4.Deploy the Function App Project to Azure.

[image]
[image]

**PS:**

I Guess you need to re-enter the Function app from the ResourceGroup to view. Maybe it just need to refresh.